# Can I modify my training datasets (X_train and Y_train) while fitting the model?

Tags: machine-learning, training

I am new to ML and I am trying to train a forecasting model. The target variable (Y_train) has multiple columns, all of Boolean type. The features table (X_train), according to my approach, in the first iteration of fitting the model should remain the same and from the next iterations, keep adding the first column from Y_train (and simultaneously deleting those columns from Y_train). The reason being that, according to how the data is structured, I think the previous Boolean columns contribute to the state of the next Boolean column. Is there a way to do this? Or is my approach completely wrong?

Comment: Hi Mookesh, Welcome to the community. Please consider upvoting/marking the answer as correct if you find anything useful on your post

Comment: Would you like to share more details about the dataset? A screenshot would be helpful.